# Nodejs Promise reject wont forward error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

Im trying to catch an error that says the file that im trying to read does not exist. i have intentionally named the file wrong.

inside my controller i have `getAllProducts()` that will return a promise, if the promise resolves then i render a page, if not then display the error to the console

```
// inside productController.js 
exports.getProductForShop = (req, res, next) => {
    productModel.getAllProducts()
        .then(products => {
            res.render('shop', {
                title: 'shop',
                products,
                path: '/'
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

inside my model class i have implemented the above mention function ie: `getAllProducts()`here is the code its a static function, if that's anything of importance

```
// inside productModel.js
static getAllProducts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('data/wrongName.json', (error, products) => { // wrong file name
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error(error)); // <-- line that sends error message
            }

            resolve(JSON.parse(products)); // this is line 52, it should not be executed
        })
    })
}
```

when i run the code i get the following error message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\NodeJs\models\productModel.js:52:30)
?[90m    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13)?[39m
```

this must mean that the `fs.readFil`e received the wrong file name, threw an error, `reject(new Error(error));` was called, still went on to execute line 52 which has `resolve();`

when i console log the error inside the `if(error)` block i get the correct error message

```
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\NodeJs\data\wrongName.json'
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\NodeJs\models\productModel.js:49:35)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13)
```

when i do `return reject(new Error(error));` i get the correct error message, same as show above.

Can someone please explain to me why the error message passed to `reject(new Error(error));` is not caught in the `catch` block ?

**Update**:
adding catch block did not work either, seems that a `return render` is the only way?! i was under the impression that reject puts the promise in a rejected state and prevents further execution

```
// inside productModel.js
static getAllProducts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('data/productseData.json', (error, products) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error(error));
            }

            resolve(JSON.parse(products));
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem after you add `return reject`? or are you asking why it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: @aw04 yes it should work _without_ `return reject` because reject call would put the promise in rejected state and prevent further execution

Comment: It’s `reject(error)`, not `reject(new Error(error))`. (And yes, you should return after rejecting. No, it should not necessarily work without `return` – execution continues, though the state of the promise can’t be changed.)

Comment: alternatively, resolve in an else block, then you don't need to return - the problem is the code at the moment is trying to `JSON.parse(undefined)` since result is most likely `undefined` if there is an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a slight misunderstanding of what's going on here. Calling `reject` will reject the promise, and the subsequent `resolve` will not resolve it. So far so good. The problem is that it won't stop execution without a `return`. So you're essentially running unnecessary code which happens to cause an error.

You should ensure that the `resolve` code is not executed in the case of an error. You can accomplish this with `return reject` or by wrapping the `resolve` in an `else` block.

Keep in mind there's nothing special about `resolve`/`reject` here. They're simple function calls and function calls do nothing to stop execution.

Comment: chances are that products won't be anything you can JSON.parse if there's an error, which would throw an error

Comment: as does resolving in an else block :p which is what I would do